# OLAP dimension hierarchy for a date including the hours

Tags: date, ssas, hierarchy, olap

I need to create the next hierarchy:
Month -> Week of Month -> Day of Week -> Hour of Day.

I use "Dimension Wizard" in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 to create a new dimension. When I am trying to create a dimension by choosing "Generate a time table on the server", the smallest time period, that can be chosen is a "Date". How to add hours to the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, the lowest granularity of a SQL time dimension is date.  You need to create both a DimDate, as well as a DimTime.  The following article provides step by step instructions for the Time Dimension.

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25852/Creating-Time-Dimension-in-Microsoft-Analysis-Serv)